# Weird shadows in cycles

Tags: shadows

I have made a render, but the shadows appear to be blocky. I already researched this topic and almost every article says to do more subsurf, but I already did a lot of it and it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance,
Ice.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a normals issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the "[terminator artifact](https://planetside.co.uk/news/terragen-4-4-67-update-release/)", and there's indeed few things you can do about it besides increasing the subsurf level to make the tiles less noticeable.

A workaround [has been added to Blender](https://twitter.com/ArtellBlender/status/1267843210719768576/photo/1) to hide this, and was [accepted on may 29th](https://developer.blender.org/D7634), but it's not yet available in the stable release.
Though it is available in the current daily build of version 2.90.

[image]